# Java generics 2 set of <K,V> or <T> in method declaration

Tags: java, generics

I have been seeing the following methods declaration but I do not understand how `<K, V>` and `<T>` are being used.

What does `public <K, V>` does in this method?

```
public <K, V> void add(K k, V v)
```

What does `static <T>` does in this method?

```
public static <T> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem)
```

Comment: These both mean exactly the same as they would mean without the generics. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: The generic parameters (`<K, V>`/`<T>`) are separate from the method modifiers (`public`/`static`), which are seperate from the return values (`int`/`void`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall, that in Java, all methods MUST be inside a class, so this method will be in some sort of class, lets say "Clazz".

`public` indicates that this method can be accessed from outside the class, by absolutely anyone.

`static` indicated that when you call this method, you don't need to call it from a specific object, but rather you can call it just by using the class name.  So you would be able to call countGreaterThen by typing `Clazz.countGreaterThan` instead of using a specific object created as an instance of `Clazz`